# Are hint answers allowed?

Tags: discussion, hint

I seem to recall reading on some help page that an answer must in fact answer the question posed. Yet I often see Hint answers, and sometimes want to answer with hints as well. So are Hint answers "allowed" or are they discouraged?

I tried searching for meta questions on "hints" but didn't immediately find anything concrete.

**EDIT**

In the "duplicate" thread, what is the final answer? Are hint answers allowed or are they not?

Comment: @amwhy: Fixed before your comment.

Comment: Your question is a duplicate of the question linked above.

Comment: @amwhy; I'm aware of that thread but I don't see a final answer to the question.

Comment: Jens It's a recent question I linked, and the fact that there are varying opinions, recently, should lead you to conclude that asking, far too soon after a duplicate, the same question, is rather ineffective.  It is most often the case that  answers that begin with: **Hint:** are actually very poor, occasionally, very occasionally, for a very few skilled users who know how to actually provide just enough information to enable an asker to proceed on their own, it may work.

Comment: @amwhy: Thank you for your comment. What I understand from this is that there is no clear policy regarding hint answers on MSE. Is this correctly understood?

Comment: Have you ever been able to function with an answer of the form: "It's not usually a good idea. However, there is currently no law forbidding doing so. ***Use your best judgement*** after viewing a couple of dozen answers given as hints, and make sure you don't repeat the mistakes made by those posting ineffectively."  That's not a license to justify writing inappropriate hints.

Comment: @amwhy: I can function very well. I just wanted to understand if there was an official policy. It seems there isn't.

Comment: As per the above linked question, there is no "official policy" and there is not a great deal of consensus about what that policy should be, or even if there should be a policy.  Basically, **use your best judgement.**

Comment: @Xander Henderson: Does this mean that my idea that I somewhere read on the Help pages that an answer must in fact answer the question posed, is wrong?

Comment: What constitutes "an answer"?  Clearly, there is a vocal contingent on MSE which believes that hints can constitute an answer (under more or less stringent circumstances, depending on the person you ask).

Comment: The concensus is that it is usually not a good idea to write as an answer, with only a "hint".  You can hint in comments.  Only very rarely is a hint effective; ***but  the fact is: there are too many answerers that think their "hints" make good answers, but in fact, are not.***  I'd suggest you not find yourself being added to the list of "too many answerers that use a hint inappropriately, believing it is sufficient for the asker (who may not be at their level of math knowledge)."

Comment: From any viable hint, the asker should be able to fully solve the problem. (That's not to say that for you, if given such a hint, you can then answer the question.)

Comment: @Xander and Amwhy: Thank you for your inputs. I must admit I'm no wiser regarding the answer to my question, though.

Comment: It seemed like a duplicate to me too; but since you insist on "definitive" I made an effort at writing up some points that are I think relatively widely accepted. It does not give an algorithm to decide what is or is not a good idea to post something particular. Just some tests.

Comment: @quid: Thank you for your effort and your post. But after reading your post, it seems to me that there is no clear answer to my question. Was Larry B then incorrect in his comment here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2913614/angle-perpendicular-lines-and-x-axis/2913620#2913620

Comment: @Jens  Why didn't you come out from the beginning to ask what is wrong with your answer.  Given your "answer" to consider, if falls short of any appropriate hint or answer.  Sorry, but it would have been better had you not wasted my time.  Larry B. was and remains correct.  Your post does not answer the question.  Now, please stop playing games with meta posts; all you managed today was to waste a number of peoples time.

Comment: It seems the post is at least prone to be misunderstood. I agree with @amWhy that you better had include the immediate motivation.

Comment: @Amwhy: My question was instigated by Larry's comment, yes, but there was no "playing of games". His comment just made me interested in whether a hint was allowed or not. Hence my question. And my answer is more than a hint, it is basically the answer.

Comment: The jocular saying is that, in England, "everything which is not forbidden is allowed", while, in Germany, the opposite applies, so "everything which is not allowed is forbidden". This may be extended to France—"everything is allowed even if it is forbidden"—and Russia where "everything is forbidden, even that which is expressly allowed". https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Everything_which_is_not_forbidden_is_allowed

Comment: @Gerry: Excellent portrayal.

Answer (score 7):

This came up recently as mentioned in a comment: 
[Is it acceptable to leave hints as answers?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28969/is-it-acceptable-to-leave-hints-as-answers)

As can be seen there the notion "hint" is not well-defined and even if it were opinions would still be mixed. Since you look for a definitive answer, let me try to record some things that are, I believe, mostly consensus.

- It is allowed to post something as an answer post that does not literally contain the answer. For example, a good description of the steps needed to solve a problem can be given in lieu of a literal answer.
- It is allowed to post a partial answer.
- Sloppy and and poorly crafted posts are discouraged. (Not all hints are sloppy, not all literal answers are not sloppy.)
- Posts prone to be misunderstood  are discouraged.
- Posts should be  able to stand a bit on their own. Of course it is sometimes, even often, not possible to be self-contained. Yet consider the thought-experiment that for an hour all links are broken. Would the post be interesting during that hour? If not, it does not stand on its own.

If somebody concludes that a posts does not meet these criteria, they might decide to  take action against it via downvote and/or delete votes. This is also allowed.

Comment: Your last point is an interesting one; it seems to capture all the cases I can think of flawlessly, including reference requests!